# Multiple 2D and 3D plots in a table with mathematica/wolfram

Tags: plotting, graphics, scripting, table

I'm a mathematica newbie!

I want to display 15 plots (5 rows labeled by "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" and 3 columns labeled by "P1" "P2" "P3"). The plots in the first two columns are regular (2D) Plot, whereas the plots in the 3rd column are actually 3DPlot.

For a first try I just focused on plotting the 10 2D plots. Even with that I don't get the table rows and columns names displayed properly (although the graphs seem correct):

```
rowHeadings = TextCell[ StringJoin[{"Row ",{"A","B","C","D","A"}[[#]]}],FontSize -> s] & /@Range[1,5];
colHeadings =TextCell[{ "P1 ","P2 "}];
Clear[format];
format[plots_, s_: 10] := TableForm[plots, 
  TableHeadings -> {rowHeadings,colHeadings}, 
  TableAlignments -> Center, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
parameters = Table[{rowID, colID},{rowID, 1, 5}, {colID, {1,2}}];
myfunc[colID,rowID,x_] :=myfunc[colID,values[[colID]],rowID,x];
myfunc[colID,rowID] := myfunc[colID,rowID,#]&;
functors = Map[myfunc[#[[2]],#[[1]] ]&,parameters,{2}];
Labeled[format[
  Map[Plot[#[x],{x,0,1},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  FrameTicks->Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 100]&,functors, {2}]],
  Style["Reward function for deviation from initial trait value", 16],Top]
```

The plots are displayed properly but the Table labels are not shown. Would anyone see why? And next how am I supposed to add the 3rd column with a 3DPlot in this kind of setting? Is it even possible with Mathematica?

Comment: Problem is you've made the entire list `{"P1","P2"}` a `TextCell`. Try `colHeadings=TextCell/@{"P1","P2"}`. Just a heads up, you probably shouldn't use `s` the way you do in `rowHeadings` for font size, it seems to work but I'm not sure why. You're leaving `s` as a global variable, while `format` should be localizing it. Better to do `rowHeadings[s_:10]:=TextCell[...,FontSize->s]` then call it with `TableHeadings->{rowHeadings[s]}`. Also, `values` in `myfunc` seems to be undefined.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea what s was doing, so thank you for pointing this out! Thanks for the TextCell fix, I will try this rn!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: "values" is not defined. Probably it should read: myfunc[colID_, rowID_] and myfunc[colID_, rowID_, x_]. TextCell is not appropriate.

Comment: In addition to Syed's links, this question about [common pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) is also a good resource since it looks like you have some of the basics down.

Comment: Wahoo these resources are clutch! Thank you people! :)